# What's the right way to insert data to a table with a relationship using plain mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: relationships]

This is the database I've created so far

```
CREATE TABLE app_user(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    password VARCHAR(40),
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
); 

CREATE TABLE app_videos(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    video_path VARCHAR(20),
    description VARCHAR(20),
    likes INT(20),
    dislikes INT(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
); 

CREATE TABLE vid_uid 
(
    video_id INT,
    user_id INT
);

ALTER TABLE vid_uid ADD FOREIGN KEY(video_id) REFERENCES app_videos(id); (..)
```

This far I've only managed to insert data, by using two queries. 
One of the inserts data to the app_users/app_videos table and the other one inserts the data into the relationship table.

How can I add data to a manytomany relationship without using several queries? 
is any "right" way to do it?

Comment: A SQL insert statement can add rows to one and only one table. That means multiple queries are required.